# :first in jquery not working in the script

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on an infinite scrolling script. I can't seem to get the first update id of the dynamically loaded content in jQuery as it shows blank in Firebug.

I seem to get the last `update_id` but not the first one. Can anyone point where it is going wrong?

```js
var load = 0;

var sess_uname = "<?php echo $session_uname;?>";
var f_uname = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['u']);?>";
var sess_count = "<?php echo $total_sess_count;?>";
var f_count = "<?php echo $total_friend_count;?>";
var funame = "<?php echo $f_uname0;?>";
$(".message").html("<div style='display: flex; justify-content: center;'><h1>Loading Posts...</h1> &nbsp;  " + spinner1 + "</div>").show();

if (sess_uname == f_uname) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      var sub = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

      load++;
      var first = $("i:first").text(); //i couldn't get the value of this one as it shows blank in firebug     
      var last = $("i:last").text();
      console.log(first + "--1---2-- " + last);

      if (load * 2 < sess_count) {
        $(".message").html("<h1>no more posts to show </h1>");
      } else {

        $.post("st&com.php", {
          "load": load,
          "sess_count": sess_count,
          "update_id2": last
        }, function(data) {
          $(".message").html(spinner1).show();
          $("#status_area").append(data);
          $(".hide").hide();
          $(".message").html(spinner1).hide();

        });
        console.log("last12");
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      load++;
      if (load * 2 > f_count) {
        $(".message").html("<h1>no more posts to show here</h1>");
      } else {

        $.post("status_list.php", {
          funame: funame,
          load: load
        }, function(data) {
          $(".message").html(spinner1).show();
          $("#status_area").append(data);
          $(".hide").hide();
          $(".message").html(spinner1).hide();

        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status_area">
  <div class="message" style="display: none;"><span class="fa fa-gear fa-spin" style="width: 5rem; height: 5rem;"></span></div>
  0:update_id 2---<br>---:update_id 1--0<i class="no" style="display:none;" no="398">398</i>
  <div type="398" class="hide hidden_edit_4_session session_editor398 jumbotron" style="display: none;"><a type="398" class="btn pull-right close_edit" title="Close without editing">Close X</a><input type="text" class="form-control title_s_edit title_s_398" name="status_title" value=" 123456" placeholder="Title"><span>&nbsp;</span><textarea id="wall_edit_398"
      type="398" rows="5" cols="50" class="session_edit text_value_398" wrap="hard" placeholder="whats up aboutthecreator">             &lt;div&gt;Vivamus elementum semper &lt;a class="btn btn-link" href="hash_sys.php?tag=qwerty"&gt;  !qwerty  &lt;/a&gt; nisi. Donec sodales sagittis magna.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Quisque rutrum. Integer tincidunt.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum.&nbsp; Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis.&lt;/div&gt;</textarea><br><span class="pull-left spinner_edit398"></span><button style="float:right;" value="398"
      type="a" class="btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit">Update</button></div><textarea class="hidden_textarea hidden_value398" disabled="">&lt;div&gt;Vivamus elementum semper !qwerty nisi. Donec sodales sagittis magna.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Quisque rutrum. Integer tincidunt.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum.&nbsp; Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis.&lt;/div&gt;</textarea>
  <div attr="398" type="398" class="statusboxes border border-warning  status_398  jumbotron">
    <h3 class="pull-left title">
      <div id="#398" attr="398" class="title_s_2copy posted" value=" 123456"> 123456</div>
    </h3><span class="pull-right"><div class="dropdown"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a attr="398" type="398" class="btn edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status">Edit</a></li>
      <li><a type="398" class="btn delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_398 glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_status_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </span><br>
  <hr>
  <legend><span style="font-size: 13.5px;" class=" data_s_2copy" type="398"><div class="descrip" data-id="398"><div>Vivamus elementum semper <a class="btn btn-link" href="hash_sys.php?tag=qwerty">  !qwerty  </a> nisi. Donec sodales sagittis magna.</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna.</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>Quisque rutrum. Integer tincidunt.</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis.</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum.&nbsp; Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis.</div> <br></div></span></legend><b class="posted"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="home.php?u=aboutthecreator"><img src="../user/user/142/ThuJul1821235420191075.jpg" height="20px" width="20px"> aboutthecreator</a> on   December 19, 19</small></b><small><br><span class="pull-left spinner_status398"></span><legend><a type="like" class="btn btn-warning status_like_398 like" attr="398">Like</a>&nbsp;<span class="label label-info">0</span> | <a type="unlike" class="btn btn-danger status_unlike_398 unlike" attr="398">Dislike</a>&nbsp;<span class="label label-info">0</span> | <a class="btn btn-primary share_btn share_398" title=" 123456" type="share" id="398">Copy</a></legend></small>
  <span
    class="edit-spinner"></span>
    <h4><a id="398" class="btn btn-default collap-btn">Comments</a></h4>
    <!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
    <div id="toggle398" class="collapse scroll-comments">

      <textarea id="reply_textarea_398" update-detail="398" class="atwho-inputor status_reply_398 input-custom2" placeholder="comment's"></textarea><span class="pull-left spinner_comment_post398"></span><button id="reply_butn_398" attr="398" type="b"
        class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm reply_butn reply_398">Reply</button><span id="status_spinner_r"></span></div>
</div><i class="no" style="display:none;" no="397">397</i>
<div type="397" class="hide hidden_edit_4_session session_editor397 jumbotron" style="display: none;"><a type="397" class="btn pull-right close_edit" title="Close without editing">Close X</a><input type="text" class="form-control title_s_edit title_s_397" name="status_title" value=" 12345" placeholder="Title"><span>&nbsp;</span><textarea id="wall_edit_397"
    type="397" rows="5" cols="50" class="session_edit text_value_397" wrap="hard" placeholder="whats up aboutthecreator">             &lt;div&gt;Vivamus &lt;a class="btn btn-link" href="hash_sys.php?tag=qwerty"&gt;  !qwerty  &lt;/a&gt;&nbsp; elementum semper nisi. Donec sodales sagittis magna.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Quisque rutrum. Integer tincidunt.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. &lt;a class="btn btn-link" href="hash_sys.php?tag=bart"&gt;  !bart  &lt;/a&gt; Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis.&lt;/div&gt;</textarea><br><span class="pull-left spinner_edit397"></span>
  <button
    style="float:right;" value="397" type="a" class="btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit">Update</button>
</div><textarea class="hidden_textarea hidden_value397" disabled="">&lt;div&gt;Vivamus !qwerty&nbsp; elementum semper nisi. Donec sodales sagittis magna.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Quisque rutrum. Integer tincidunt.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis.&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. !bart Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis.&lt;/div&gt;</textarea>
<div attr="397" type="397" class="statusboxes border border-warning  status_397  jumbotron">
  <h3 class="pull-left title">
    <div id="#397" attr="397" class="title_s_2copy posted" value=" 12345"> 12345</div>
  </h3><span class="pull-right"><div class="dropdown"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a attr="397" type="397" class="btn edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a type="397" class="btn delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_397 glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_status_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</span><br>
<hr>
<legend><span style="font-size: 13.5px;" class=" data_s_2copy" type="397"><div class="descrip" data-id="397"><div>Vivamus <a class="btn btn-link" href="hash_sys.php?tag=qwerty">  !qwerty  </a>&nbsp; elementum semper nisi. Donec sodales sagittis magna.</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna.</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>Quisque rutrum. Integer tincidunt.</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis.</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. <a class="btn btn-link" href="hash_sys.php?tag=bart">  !bart  </a> Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis.</div> <br></div></span></legend><b class="posted"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="home.php?u=aboutthecreator"><img src="../user/user/142/ThuJul1821235420191075.jpg" height="20px" width="20px"> aboutthecreator</a> on   December 19, 19</small></b><small><br><span class="pull-left spinner_status397"></span><legend><a type="like" class="btn btn-warning status_like_397 like" attr="397">Like</a>&nbsp;<span class="label label-info">0</span> | <a type="unlike" class="btn btn-danger status_unlike_397 unlike" attr="397">Dislike</a>&nbsp;<span class="label label-info">0</span> | <a class="btn btn-primary share_btn share_397" title=" 12345" type="share" id="397">Copy</a></legend></small>
<span
  class="edit-spinner"></span>
  <h4><a id="397" class="btn btn-default collap-btn">Comments</a></h4>
  <!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
  <div id="toggle397" class="collapse scroll-comments">

    <textarea id="reply_textarea_397" update-detail="397" class="atwho-inputor status_reply_397 input-custom2" placeholder="comment's"></textarea><span class="pull-left spinner_comment_post397"></span><button id="reply_butn_397" attr="397" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm reply_butn reply_397">Reply</button>
    <span
      id="status_spinner_r"></span>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

after a lot of googling i found the answer to print :first value. It seems the sum approach to grab the value previously was wrong. The best method is to actually wrap it in a class and then call it eg) previously it was  `var first = $("i:first").text();` but it should be like this, i wrapped it around a  tag with a class and called it like  `var first=$(".i-select i:first").text();` and now i get the first value. Thanks for the help @freedom_m.

Comment: Please read [mcve].  There's *far* too much code needed to demonstrate your issue.  SO isn't meant to be a debugging service.  In the process of picking out the relevant html/code you may also find your issue yourself, so a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: Replace all your provide js with `console.log($("i:first").text())` and it works fine - so the issue is clearly not with `:first` as asserted, so must be something else.

Comment: @freedomn-m i tried your method still it's blank.

Comment: @freedomn-m maybe you are an expert who can work without the html element but there are still a lot of experts who still require the code to pinpoint what's happening if i didn't provide it i would be getting negative votes for being incomplete.

Comment: Ok, let me ask you - you're asking about `:first` not working - which is one of the first lines in the code.  Do you think 2x `$.post` which occur after that might, in anyway, affect the earlier code or have any relevance/impact on that code?

Comment: cant you see in the code and conclude from the comment where it is, you ask for minimal code, if i post it then someone else will ask for the whole code what shall i do get the rules straight @freedomn-m

Comment: To clarify: Minimal code **to reproduce the problem**.  I feel your frustration, but no, I'm not wading through all that code to look for why it's not working, when the line by itself clearly works (ie so there's something else causing it not to work, either in this code or in code not provided) - and given the lack of responses, it looks like no-one else wants to wade through all that HTML either.

Comment: There's a voting option on questions and it's (currently) worded as: "It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and **the shortest code necessary to *reproduce* the problem**." - just to clarify that it's not just me / my opinion, it's part of SO.

Comment: if you are using the last version of Jquery that is deprecated, being sure that the version that you have allows you to use it https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: @UserEsp i use v 3.3.1 i don't think that's deprecated sir